# How do i use a new Phil's routedebugger

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, routes

Try to use, but do not understand what should i do for enabling of it.

tried the old style but it doesnt work for me:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

here the link to post: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply [install the NuGet package](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx) which will add the assembly reference to your project and you are good to go. It will print route information on the bottom of each page. It uses the microsoft dynamic infrastructure to add an http module at runtime. So all you need is to run the following command in the NuGet package console window:

```
PM> Install-Package RouteDebugger
```

and then run your application.

Comment: Installed, works in existing routes but what about non-existing? i tried but it doesnt work: http://goo.gl/hBxx9
the big point of this project is to show route info :-D

Comment: @msony, what about non-existing routes? If you get a 404 it means that none of your routes matched the request. What other information are you expecting in this case?

Comment: With the latest version you have to add 
<add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="true" />  to the web.config file to make it work.

Answer (score 16):

Installing through NuGet adds a line to your web.config.  For some reason this didn't happen for me and it didn't work.

Make sure this line is in your "appSettings" in your web.config:

```
<add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Accepted answer is not complete without this

Comment: If you are using config transformations verify that this value is removed or set to false

Answer (score 9):

If you are still having problems, make sure you don't have `optimizeCompilations="true"` setting in your web.config.

Comment: This fixed it for me.  Thanks.  Any idea why that breaks it?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason it is not working is that you have the next route:

```
routes.MapRoute(url: "{*data}", ...);
```

This route catches all requests where not caught by previous routes.